# How can I animate a div to the right when it is pressed, and then, when it is pressed again, return it back to its first position with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have multiple clickable panels made with Bootstrap class *panel*, organized in this way:

[Image of my website naoh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuh3F.jpg)

For example, when I click on the first panel, some other panels appear and cool stuff happens.

[When you click a panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kfDJ.jpg)

**But** I want that the panel that I clicked to be at the center. And then, when that same panel is clicked, I want to return everything to normal (which right now works with the specific panels per panel), including the main panel, so it should move to the left. The panels at the center doesn't require animation, and the right ones should animate to the left and back to the right.

Here is my jQuery code for the panels, lets say *panel 2*:

```
//Panel 2
if ($("#panel_2").data("clicked")) {
    $(".navegadores").toggle(function () { });
} else {
    $(".navegadores").hide();
}

$("#panel_2").click(function () {
    $("#panel_2").data('clicked', true);
    $(".navegadores").toggle(function () { });
    console.log($("#panel_2").data("clicked"));
});
```

I feel I would need to use the **.toggle** method somehow, or the **.slideToggle**, but I'm quite confused atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
$('#panel2').click(function(){
   if ( $(this).data('clickstate') == 0 ){
     $(this).animate({
       marginLeft: '200px'
     },1000, function(){
        $(this).data('clickstate', '1');
     });
   }else{
     $(this).animate({
       marginLeft: '0'
     },1000, function(){
        $(this).data('clickstate', '0');
     });
   }
});
```

```css
#panel2{position:relative;height:100px;width:100px;background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="panel2" data-clickstate="0"></div>
```